# TListBox sync with TStringList

Tags: delphi

I've got a background thread sending messages to the main thread which, in turn, adds the messages to a TListBox like a log.

Thing is, this background thread is really fast and I dont really need to update the log that fast. I'd like to add the messages to a TStringList and set a timer to update the TListBox every second or so.

I've tried using:

```
listBox1.Items := StringList1;
```

or

```
listBox1.Items.Assign(StringList1);
```

in the OnTimer event and it works. Thing is, it never let's the user really scroll or click the listbox, because it refreshes every second.

I'm using Delphi XE4

Is there a more elegant way to sync the contents of the listbox with this background StringList (or any other list if necessary)? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What Delphi version? (Functionality changes with newer versions.) Do you have some code that will make it more clear what you're trying now that isn't working the way you'd like?

Comment: Use a virtual list view

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Use a virtual approach

Set the `Style` property of the ListBox to `lbVirtual`, and assign the `OnData` event to let it request the strings needed for painting the control, rather then owning the strings which resets the whole control on every single update. Illustrative code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, Classes, Controls, Forms, AppEvnts, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ApplicationEvents1: TApplicationEvents;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListBox1Data(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
      var Data: String);
    procedure ApplicationEvents1Idle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FStrings: TStringList;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FStrings := TStringList.Create;
  FStrings.CommaText := 'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z';
  ListBox1.Count := FStrings.Count;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FStrings.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1Data(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  var Data: String);
begin
  Data := FStrings[Index];
end;

procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Idle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
begin
  FStrings[Random(FStrings.Count)] := Chr(65 + Random(26));
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Invalidate;
end;

end.
```

In this example I use the `OnIdle` event of a `TApplicationEvents` component to simulate your threaded updates of the StringList. Note that you now can scroll and select items in the ListBox, despite of the 1 second update interval of the Timer.

#### Syncronizing the item count

Changes in item count of the StringList also needs to be reflected in the ListBox. This needs be done by `ListBox1.Count := FStrings.Count`, but then the ListBox appearance will be reset again. Thus a workaround is needed by temporarily preventing it from redrawing/updating alltogether:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Random(2) = 0 then
  begin
    FStrings.Add('A');
    SyncListCounts;
  end
  else
    ListBox1.Invalidate;
end;

procedure TForm1.SyncListCounts;
var
  SaveItemIndex: Integer;
  SaveTopIndex: Integer;
begin
  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    SaveItemIndex := ListBox1.ItemIndex;
    SaveTopIndex := ListBox1.TopIndex;
    ListBox1.Count := FStrings.Count;
    ListBox1.ItemIndex := SaveItemIndex;
    ListBox1.TopIndex := SaveTopIndex;
  finally
    ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Can't I just use ListBox1.BeginUpdate / EndUpdate instead of the SendMessages?

Comment: Well, `TListBox` doesn't have those routines, but the `Items` property has. I hadn't thought about it though, and now it seems that `StdCtrls.TListBoxStrings.SetUpdateState` sends exactly the same `WM_SETREDRAW` message, I agree that is preferred semantically speaking. +1